# Wrong info in user's "bounties" tab when there is an active bounty

Tags: bug, bounty

This minor bug is in the user's offered bounties tab:

`http://stackoverflow.com/users/<id>/<name>?tab=bounties&sort=offered`

When a user offers a bounty for a question for a question they had already offered one, the tooltip for the previous bounty shows

[image: this question has an open bounty]

instead of the standard
[image: this question had a bounty]

(and, of course, the actual bounty)
[image]

This may also be the case for past bounties for questions with open bounties not offered by the current user.